# Woocommerce disable order number for specific status

Tags: woocommerce

Hello I have the following problem at the moment.
I have sequential order numbers in my shop.

However, I always have problems that order numbers are not sequential, because woocommerce assigns an order number for each status.

Is it possible to deactivate the order numbers for special statuses?

Another possibility would be to generate the order number only for the status "on-hold" and "shipped".

Is it possible to delete an order with the status "X" after a time of "X" seconds?